# How to get a TkInter GUI (not a shell prompt) to Listen for Input from /dev/stdin

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a Python programme with a GUI which listens for an RFID token being presented (using a USB reader which emulates keyboard input). I'm having issues whereby keyboard/RFID input is only listened for and acted upon if the Terminal from which I launch the script has focus.

**If the GUI is focussed**, all input is ignored but when the terminal has focus, it works fine and even sends updates to the GUI as well as shell. I've tried drawing a text input box on the GUI, but that didn't work.

I'm wondering if it's something to do with how it needs to use either multiple threads, queues or even processes - can anyone help me to understand it better?

Code is below, thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import MySQLdb

try:
    # python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except ImportError:
    # python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

from threading import Thread

class Fullscreen_Window:

def __init__(self):
    self.tk = tk.Tk()
    self.tk.title("Listening for RFID token...")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.tk)
    self.frame.pack()

    self.tk.attributes('-zoomed', True)
    self.state = False
    self.tk.bind("<F11>", self.toggle_fullscreen)
    self.tk.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)
    self.tk.config(cursor="none")

    t = Thread(target=self.listen_rfid)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
    self.state = not self.state  # Just toggling the boolean
    self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state)
    return "break"

def end_fullscreen(self, event=None):
    self.state = False
    self.tk.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    return "break"

def listen_rfid(self):
    dbHost = 'localhost'
    dbName = 'python'
    dbUser = 'python'
    dbPass = 'PASSWORD'

    dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbHost, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass, db=dbName)
    cur = dbConnection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    with open('/dev/stdin', 'r') as tty:
        while True:
            RFID_input = tty.readline().rstrip()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM access_list WHERE rfid_code = '%s'" % (RFID_input))

            if cur.rowcount != 1:
                print("ACCESS DENIED")
                ttk.Label(self.tk, text="ACCESS DENIED").pack()
            else:
                user_info = cur.fetchone()
                print("Welcome %s!!" % (user_info['name']))
                ttk.Label(self.tk, text="Welcome %s!!" % (user_info['name'])).pack()
    tty.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
w = Fullscreen_Window()
w.tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

After much head scratching, I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/562434/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-hosts-keyboard-when-connected-via-ssh) again and re-read it properly, then realised it contained the answer I was after, albeit with a tiny bit of work needed from me.

My `listen_rfid` function now looks like the code below. Hope it's useful for anyone stumbling across my problem!

The key thing is to look in `/dev/input/by-id` and find your device, there will be a symlink (at least there was on my Raspbian install) to something more elegant like, in my case, "`/event0`" - as below). You can then use python-evdev to read it.

If you don't have python-evdev, just install it with `sudo pip install evdev`

Here's the working code:

```
def listen_rfid(self):
    dbHost = 'localhost'
    dbName = 'python'
    dbUser = 'python'
    dbPass = 'PASSWORD'

    dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbHost, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass, db=dbName) # ToDo: This needs some error handling for if MySQL has gone away, and reconnect.
    cur = dbConnection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    from evdev import InputDevice
    from select import select

    keys = "X^1234567890XXXXqwertzuiopXXXXasdfghjklXXXXXyxcvbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')
    rfid_presented = ""

    while True:
       r,w,x = select([dev], [], [])
       for event in dev.read():
            if event.type==1 and event.value==1:
                    if event.code==28:
                        #print("RFID: " + str(rfid_presented))

                        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM access_list WHERE rfid_code = '%s'" % (rfid_presented))

                        if cur.rowcount != 1:
                            #print("ACCESS DENIED")
                            ttk.Label(self.tk, text="ACCESS DENIED").pack()
                        else:
                            user_info = cur.fetchone()
                            #print("Welcome %s!!" % (user_info['name']))
                            ttk.Label(self.tk, text="Welcome %s!!" % (user_info['name'])).pack()

                        rfid_presented = ""
                    else:
                        rfid_presented += keys[ event.code ]
```